# foreach looping with javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel

Please help me

how to enter sql database into javascript

> HTML

```
<table width="100%">
<tbody class="input_fields_Pesanan">
<tr>
<td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Kode BMN</b></td>
<td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Nama Barang</b></td>
<td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Kuantitas</b></td>
<td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Satuan Ukuran</b></td>
<td style="width: 2%;"></td>
```

```
<tr>
<td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="kode_bmn" name="kode_bmn" data-placeholder="--Pilih Kode BMN--">
    <option></option>

    @foreach($bmn as $b)
        <option>{{$b->kode_bmn}}-{{$b->nama_bmn}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select></td>    
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control " id="jenis_barang" name="jenis_barang" ></td>
        <td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas"></td>
        <td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="satuan_ukuran" name="satuan_ukuran" data-placeholder="--Pilih Satuan Ukuran--">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>m</option>
                                <option>unit</option>
                                <option>kg</option>
                            </select></td>
        <td>&nbsp;<button class="add_field_pesanan" title="Tambah Field Pesanan"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
  </tr>
<!-- <tr><td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="kode_bmn" name="kode_bmn" data-placeholder="--Pilih Kode BMN--"><option></option>@foreach($bmn as $b)<option>{{$b->kode_bmn}}-{{$b->nama_bmn}}</option>@endforeach</select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control " id="jenis_barang" name="jenis_barang" ></td><td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas"></td><td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="satuan_ukuran" name="satuan_ukuran" data-placeholder="--Pilih Satuan Ukuran--">
<option></option><option>m</option><option>unit</option><option>kg</option></select></td><td>&nbsp;<button class="add_field_button" title="Tambah Field Pesanan"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td></tr> -->
     </tbody> 
  </table>
```

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper_pesanan  = $(".input_fields_Pesanan"); //Fields wrapper
var add_pesanan      = $(".add_field_pesanan"); //Add button ID


var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_pesanan).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper_pesanan).append('<tr><td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="kode_bmn" name="kode_bmn" data-placeholder="--Pilih Kode BMN--"><option></option>@foreach($bmn as $b)<option>{{$b->kode_bmn}}-{{$b->nama_bmn}}</option>@endforeach</select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control " id="jenis_barang" name="jenis_barang" ></td><td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas"></td><td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="satuan_ukuran" name="satuan_ukuran" data-placeholder="--Pilih Satuan Ukuran--"><option></option><option>m</option><option>unit</option><option>kg</option></select></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_pesanan" title="Hapus"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td></tr>'); // add input boxes.
    }
});


$(wrapper_pesanan).on("click",".remove_pesanan", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})
```

});

how to enter sql database into javascript
when adding new fields the database is unreadable

```
@foreach($bmn as $b)
        <option>{{$b->kode_bmn}}-{{$b->nama_bmn}}</option>
        @endforeach
```

the foreach in html cannot be declared by javascript, how can the foreach in html be read by javascript

[image]

Comment: It's a pretty complex UI, and I think jQuery couldn't enough. Please consider use Vue.js that bundled in Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't use blade templating in JS** files.

Now you have **2 things you can do**:

1. Move your snippet of javascript from js file to the bottom of the "view.blade.php"
2. You can declare in the "view.blade.php" the variables that contain options, and then get it from javascript.

For example:

Your "view.blade.php" would be:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody class="input_fields_Pesanan">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Kode BMN</b></td>
            <td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Nama Barang</b></td>
            <td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Kuantitas</b></td>
            <td style="width: 15%;" align="center"><b>Satuan Ukuran</b></td>
            <td style="width: 2%;"></td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="kode_bmn" name="kode_bmn" data-placeholder="--Pilih Kode BMN--">
                    <option></option>
                    @foreach($bmn as $b)
                    <option>{{$b->kode_bmn}}-{{$b->nama_bmn}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td>    
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control " id="jenis_barang" name="jenis_barang" ></td>
            <td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas"></td>
            <td>
                <select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select2" id="satuan_ukuran" name="satuan_ukuran" data-placeholder="--Pilih Satuan Ukuran--">
                    <option></option>
                    <option>m</option>
                    <option>unit</option>
                    <option>kg</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;<button class="add_field_pesanan" title="Tambah Field Pesanan"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
</table>
<script>
    var myOptions = '@foreach($bmn as $b) <option>{{$b->kode_bmn}}-{{$b->nama_bmn}}</option> @endforeach';
</script>
```

And then your Javascript file would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper_pesanan = $(".input_fields_Pesanan"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_pesanan = $(".add_field_pesanan"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_pesanan).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper_pesanan).append('<tr><td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select-new-' + x + '" id="kode_bmn" name="kode_bmn" data-placeholder="--Pilih Kode BMN--"><option></option>' + myOptions + '</select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control " id="jenis_barang" name="jenis_barang" ></td><td><input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="kuantitas" name="kuantitas"></td><td><select type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="form-control select-new-' + x + '" id="satuan_ukuran" name="satuan_ukuran" data-placeholder="--Pilih Satuan Ukuran--"><option></option><option>m</option><option>unit</option><option>kg</option></select></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="remove_pesanan" title="Hapus"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></td></tr>'); // add input boxes.

            //instantiate the new select as select2
            $('select.select-new-' + x).select2();
        }
    });

    $(wrapper_pesanan).on("click",".remove_pesanan", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
    });
});
```

Obviously **make sure the snippet** in view.blade.php comes **before** of including your javascript, otherwise you get a undefined from javascript.

Comment: first I want to say thank you from me,.
how to select2 still have a search function?

Comment: After you have appended you have to re-instantiate the new select, first remove "select2" from the append string because it means select2 has already instantiated, second I suggest you to give for example a class like "select-new-x" where x is for example your variable x, then after append you can re-instantiate select2 normally like `$('select-new-'+x).select2();` let me know if you want a sample :)

Comment: I have edit the javascript section of the answer, check it out :) **not tested, let me know**

Comment: Dont understand... English

Comment: sorry :)
successful, but when the first addrow field there is no search function.
what if all of the search functions still exist?

Comment: I've not tested but in theory they should all have research

Comment: can you help me

Comment: Now what is the provlem? :)

Comment: when adding an addrow,
the first line does not appear search function

Comment: Only for understand if i have understand you. If you dont add any row everithing works, otherwise if you add rows the search only works in the added rows? (Sorry but im writing from mobile ahah)

Comment: What if all the rows have a search function in select2?

Comment: It is normal, is what you want, no?

Comment: what I want is that when adding addrow the search function in all fields continues to work

Comment: Could you put screenshot?